# Ошибка инсталяции NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, установка

Всем доброго времени суток!
При попытке установки через pycharm модуля numpy мне установщик выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как устранить данную ошибку?
Заранее спасибо!!
Версия пайтона: 3.8
Версия pycharm  [image: версия]

Comment: как ты устанавшиваешь?

Comment: Я начал вбивать import numpy as np и мне высветилась подсказка, что данный модуль не установлен и программа предложила установить его. Я нажал установить, а далее в логе была эта ошибка.

Comment: А ОС какая? Это может быть важно

Comment: Добрый день! windows 10 x 64 версия 10.0.18363

Я пробовал ещё ставить через командную строку и pip install numpy
Вот что пишет система :

C:\Users\хххххх>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\хххххх\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (1.18.5)

Comment: очевидно, у вас не один python на пк, и вы пытаетесь использовать numpy  в том, где не установили библиотеку

Comment: я смотрел видос об этом, и удалил второй питон ещё до того, как разместил здесь пост. Питон на компе, по крайней мере согласно "установке и удалению программ" у меня 1. Так же если ввести в командную строку 'python' , то она указывает на наличие только одной версии.